# JScript in html is not running or being called

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wrote an html code that shows the user the terms of use however I faced a problem that I think it is because of the script issues.
I  tried my code on JSFIDDLE tool it worked with me, but in my browser it did not.

[image: Screenshot 1]

[image: Screenshot 2]

My code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Terms of Use</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="$PORTAL_ACTION$" class="login">
 <h1>Terms of Use</h1>
 <p class="login-p">
  To continue please read and accept the following terms.
 </p>
 <br>
 <textarea class="login-input" readonly>
1.plapla
2.plapla
3.plapla </textarea>
 <br>
 <textarea class="login-input" readonly>
1.plapla
2.plapla
3.plapla </textarea>
 <div>
  <input type="checkbox" name="option-1" id="option-1"><label for="option-1">Accept</label>
 </div>
 <div>
  <input type="submit" value="Continue" disabled>
 </div>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js">
var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"),
    submitButt = $("input[type='submit']");
checkboxes.click(function() {
    submitButt.attr("disabled", !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
}); 
    </script>
  
 <p class="footer">
  © 2015 Powered by <a href="http://www.tavit.aero">TAV-IT</a>.
 </p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The problem is that when I check the checkbox the script should disable the btn but it does not :(

Comment: Sorry, the script should enable the btn not disable it.

Comment: So edit the question.

Comment: You're missing a <script> tag before your inline JS.

Comment: It worked fine after declaring an empty script in the header. Now I want to change the style of the textareas scroll bar to tiny scroll bar, could you help me ??

Thank you alot

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your inline script should be in its own `<script>` tag. Like so (note the extra closing and opening script tags):

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
    var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"),
        submitButt = $("input[type='submit']");
    checkboxes.click(function() {
        submitButt.attr("disabled", checkboxes.is(":checked"));
    }); 
</script>
```

See [this Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3h3XSsCyjSrp0CZOvqAX?p=preview) to see the amended version working.

Answer (score 1):

Your JS code that accesses DOM elements should run after DOM ready, e.g.,

```
$(function() {
  var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']")
    , submitButt = $("input[type='submit']")
    ;

  checkboxes.click(function() {
    submitButt.attr("disabled", !checkboxes.is(":checked"));
  });
});
```

and should be wrapped in `<script>` tags.

Comment: This shouldn't matter as his script is at the end of the body.

Comment: @shennan Actually it isn't.

Comment: It's after the elements he's using, though.

Comment: Depending on browser DOM rendering processes seems like a terrifically bad idea.

Comment: it's pretty common practise to pop script tags just before the end of a body.

Comment: @shennan Yes, it is, but this is not what the OP did, and IMO (YMMV) you should never rely on being able to access DOM elements outside of a DOM ready event.

Comment: The OP's script tags *are* after the elements he is using. The issue with the OP's code is not the location of his script tags but the fact he has used his `jquery` library script tags to wrap his inline code. The fact is, as it stands your answer does not fix his issue.

Comment: @shennan Other than saying it should be wrapped in `<script>` tags, and that it should be in a DOM-ready function, I agree. You'll have to continue this one without me.

Comment: It works without the DOM-ready function. It does not work without the *added* script tags. Your last line is an afterthought, brought about from my answer. But yes, I'll continue alone now... :-)

Comment: @shennan I didn't see your answer until 5-10 minutes after your first comment, but whatever. Sorry you're so annoyed by... well, I don't know, but still whatever.

Comment: Not annoyed, just trying to get you to improve your answer. You've been around the block on SO so I expected a bit more of an accurate answer is all. Never mind.

Answer (score 1):

as per the `HTML5` Guidelines for `script` tag [Link](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/semantics.html#the-script-element)

> "If there is a src attribute, the element must be either empty or
>   contain only script documentation that also matches script content
>   restrictions. "

So you should not have code in `<script>` tag with `src` attribute . rather create an empty `script` tag having `src` attribute and then create new `script` to add your script code

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>
    var checkboxes = $("input[type='checkbox']"),
        submitButt = $("input[type='submit']");
    checkboxes.click(function() {
        submitButt.attr("disabled", checkboxes.is(":checked"));
    }); 
</script>
```